# What is the return type of a lambda expression if an item of a vector is returned?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std-function, return-type-deduction

Consider the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int>v = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
    std::function<const int&(int)> f = [&v](int i) { return v[i];}; 
    std::function<const int&(int)> g = [&v](int i) -> const int& { return v[i];};

    std::cout << f(3) << ' ' << g(3) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the same result: in `f`, `v` is passed by const reference, so `v[i]` should have `const int&` type.

However, I get the result

```
 0 3
```

If I do not use std::function, everything is fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int>v = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
    auto f = [&v](int i) { return v[i];}; 
    auto g = [&v](int i) -> const int& { return v[i];};

    std::cout << f(3) << ' ' << g(3) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
3 3
```

Thus I'm wondering:

1. In the second snippet, what is the return type of the lambda expression `f`? Is `f` the same as `g`?
2. In the first snippet, what happened when the `std::function f` was constructed, causing the error?

Comment: @0x499602D2 using ideone, c++14. http://ideone.com/gkAorj

Comment: Oddly enough, it gives a [segmentation fault](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Vnf1dCbOqHmMlBAQ) in the latest version of gcc.

Comment: More specifically, the segfault happens on `f(3)` but not `g(3)`.

Comment: `v is passed by const reference, so v[i] should have const int& type.` No. `v` is captured by reference and `v[i]` is therefore non-const `int&`. I'm not sure if it should make a difference in this case. Seems to have [expected output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ee2db4821cefa93) in gcc 4.9.2

Comment: This looks buggy to me BUT it could also be a consequence of the lambda capture ref becoming dangling. I'd have to scan the standard. And this is why C++11 is terrible.

Comment: @user2079303 I think that's the brainfart. It's **not** passed by const reference. The _reference_ is const, but the object referred to is mutable. References are not reseatable anyawyas, so they're implicitly always "const" (cf. pointers, where the distinction does make sense. Capturing a pointer indeed captures _the pointer_ as const (but the pointer may refer to a non-const object).

Comment: `std::function<const T&(blah)>` is **always** undefined behaviour if the target function returns `T` by value (which your first lambda does) because you get a dangling reference. The C++ standards committee is considering making it ill-formed.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit, it's not the captured reference that dangles, it's the `std::function<const int&(int)>::operator()` return value which is dangling, because it's bound to a local temporary inside `std::function<const int&(int)>::operator()(int)`

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Oh, right - that's a little more obvious than I thought it'd be.

Answer (score 20):

The return type of a lambda uses the `auto` return type deduction rules, which strips the referenceness. (Originally it used a slightly different set of rules based on lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (which also removed the reference), but that was changed by [a DR](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1048).)

Hence, `[&v](int i) { return v[i];};` returns `int`. As a result, in `std::function<const int&(int)> f = [&v](int i) { return v[i];};`, calling `f()` returns a dangling reference. Binding a reference to a temporary extends the lifetime of the temporary, but in this case the binding happened deep inside `std::function`'s machinery, so by the time `f()` returns, the temporary is gone already.

`g(3)` is fine because the `const int &` returned is bound directly to the vector element `v[i]`, so the reference is never dangling.

Comment: g(3) returns a reference to int in vector's internal storage, right? So is it possible that (theoretically) vector could reallocate and make this reference invalid?

Answer (score 13):

> What is the return type of a lambda expression if an item of a vector is returned?

That's the wrong question.

You should be asking what is the return type of a lambda expression *if it is not specified explicitly?*.

The answer is given in C++11 5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda] paragraph 5, where it says if the lambda has no `return expr;` statement it returns `void`, otherwise:

> the type of the returned expression after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1), array-to-pointer conversion (4.2), and function-to-pointer conversion (4.3);

<sub>(See T.C.'s comment below for DR 1048 which changed this rule slightly, and compilers actually implement the changed rule, but it doesn't matter in this case.)</sub>

lvalue-to-rvalue conversion means that if the return statement returns an lvalue like `v[i]` it decays to an rvalue, i.e. it returns just `int` by value.

So the problem with your code is that the lambda returns a temporary, but the `std::function<const int&(int)>` that wraps it binds a reference to that temporary. When you try to print out the value the temporary has aalready gone away (it was bound to an object a stack frame that no longer exists) so you have undefined behaviour.

The fix is to use `std::function<int(int)>` or ensure the lambda returns a valid reference, not an rvalue.

In C++14 non-lambdas can also use return type deduction, e.g.:

```
auto f(std::vector<int>& v, int i) { return v[i]; }
```

This follows similar (but not identical) rules to the C++11 rules for lambdas, so the return type is `int`. To return a reference you need to use:

```
decltype(auto) f(std::vector<int>& v, int i) { return v[i]; }
```

Comment: @T.C., yup, but that doesn't actually change the result here, does it? I referenced C++11 5.1.2 intentionally, not just 5.1.2, because the question is tagged c++11. I realise the DR is considered a fix against C++11, but since it doesn't actually change the result here I went with the wording in C++11 as published.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: I added a note anyway, to clarify that in practice compilers should be following the C++14 rule even in C++11 mode. Thanks for finding the relevant DR :)

Comment: You should also amend your final statement, since post-DR, these rules *are* identical to those used by `auto`, if I understand correctly.

Comment: You can also use (in C++14) `decltype(auto)` as the return type of the lambda, `[&v](int i) -> decltype(auto) {return v[i];}`, similarly to auto type deduction for regular functions.

Comment: @KRyan, no, post-DR1048 neither lambdas nor normal functions use the "C++11 rules for lambdas". Both lambdas and normal functions use the rules in [temp.deduct.call], which are not the same as the rules in C++11's [expr.prim.lambda]. They are similar, but not identical.

Answer (score 5):

1. I assume the first lambda might return `int` or `int&`¹. Not `const int&` as the reference `v` is not to a const object (it doesn't matter that the capture itself is not mutable, since that's the reference itself)
2. Life times of temporaries get extended to the end of the enclosing scope when bound to a const-ref

---

¹ I'll try to dive into that later. For now, I'm going with regular deduction intuition and say that `auto` would decuce `int`, whereas `auto&` would deduce `int&`, so I expect that the actual return type is `int`. If anyone beats me to it, all the better. I won't have time for a few hours

See the test supplied by @milleniumbug: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0309c80c364fc0cf)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks, @milleniumbug. Mind if I edit it in? (You may edit it out if I'm not responsive). That doesn't quite explain the compiler behaviour then. _(Arrg. No time to concentrate)_

Comment: The constness of `v` is not really relevant, the lambda's deduced return type decays (like an `auto` return, as T.C.'s answer says) and so is `int` irrespective of whether `v[i]` is const or not.